# Iterate through an enumerable while preserving Ember.js bindings.

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I iterate through an array/enumerable in Ember, while preserving the `get` and `set` functionality?

Fiddle with what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lv4SF/6/

I have an action that iterates through 'widgets' and marks them disabled. How can I iterate through an array of widgets while allowing for something like `widget.set('disabled', true)`.

The alternative of doing `model.set('widgets.' + index + '.disabled', true)` seems very hacky.

Answer (score 2):

You're receiving that error because the objects in your array are not instances of `Ember.Object`.

Here is an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv4SF/8/